# Is there a need for transitivity in Python __eq__?

Tags: python, class, equality

I'm implementing my own class, with custom `__eq__`. And I'd like to return `True` for things that are not "equal" in a mathematical sense, but "match" in a fuzzy way.

An issue with this is, however, that this leads to loss of transitivity in a mathematical sense, i.e. `a == b && b ==c`, while `a` may not be equal to `c`.

Question: is Python dependent on `__eq__` being transitive? Will what I'm trying to do break things, or is it possible to do this as long as I'm careful myself not to assume transitivity?

### Use case

I want to match telephone numbers with one another, while those may be either formatted internationally, or just for domestic use (without a country code specified). If there's no country code specified, I'd like a number to be equal to a number with one, but if it is specified, it should only be equal to numbers with the same country-code, or without one.

So:

- Of course, `+31 6 12345678` should equal `+31 6 12345678`, and `06 12345678` should equal `06 12345678`
- `+31 6 12345678` should equal `06 12345678` (and v.v.)
- `+49 6 12345678` should equal `06 12345678` (and v.v.)
- But `+31 6 12345678` should not be equal to `+49 6 12345678`

I don't have a need for hashing (and so won't implement it), so that at least makes life easier.

Comment: If it's not transitive, it's not equality. You can misuse equality to mean something different if you want to: it's your code. But if you (for instance) put these values into collections or try and use any library function that assumes equality is equality, it might cause you problems.

Comment: Python itself won't break, but *your code* might, exactly in the kind of example you give: if `a == b == c` may be true but `a == c` may be false, then you'll need to be very careful with your conditionals.

Comment: XY-problem interjection: I feel it'd be easier and more maintainable to first normalize the telephone numbers (i.e. expand with the local country code determined from address and remove chars not valid in a phone number), then compare them.

Comment: `a == b` just calls your function `a.__eq__(b)`. As other commentators pointed out, you can define that however you want, but you have to live with the consequences. Personally, I wouldn't go down the `__eq__` route, but define another method like `fuzzy_match`, especially since `__eq__` in terms of string equality might still be useful in your case.

Comment: Also don't forget about the `__eq__` and `__hash__` relationship: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: @orithena, I'm also normalizing them, just kept it brief for the question. Still, I'd like a "number of unknown country" to match with any country, so just assuming all numbers are Dutch (where I'm from) won't work.

Comment: EmilBode: This still sounds as if your comparison is only needed for a specific purpose. Which means that you'd be potentially breaking any other purpose (think Data Transfer Objects: if the user edits their phone number just to add the country code, other developers' code might decide "it's equal to the saved state, no need to save to backend/DB"). I'd go down the route that @mcsoini suggested: specific methods for specific purposes.

Comment: use of `__eq__` for this would be really bad in terms of code readability as it goes against intuition. Just create a member method, e.g. `equal_without_country_code` or something. Don't override the default method with something it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no MUST but a SHOULD relation for comparisons being consistent with the commonly understood relations. Python expressively does not enforce this and `float` is an inbuilt type with different behaviour due to `float("nan")`.

> #### [Expressions: Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons)
>
> […]
> User-defined classes that customize their comparison behavior should follow some consistency rules, if possible:
>
> - […]
> - **Comparison should be symmetric.** In other words, the following expressions should have the same result:
>
>   - `x == y` and `y == x`
>   - `x != y` and `y != x`
>   - `x < y` and `y > x`
>   - `x <= y` and `y >= x`
> - **Comparison should be transitive.** The following (non-exhaustive) examples illustrate that:
>
>   - x > y and y > z implies x > z
>   - x < y and y <= z implies x < z
>
> **Python does not enforce these consistency rules. In fact, the not-a-number values are an example for not following these rules.**

Still, keep in mind that exceptions are incredibly rare and subject to being ignored: most people would treat `float` as having total order, for example. Using uncommon comparison relations can seriously increase maintenance effort.

---

Canonical ways to model "fuzzy matching" via operators are as *subset*, *subsequence* or *containment* using *unsymmetric* operators.

- The `set` and `frozenset` support `>`, `>=` and so on to indicate that one set encompases all values of another.

  ```py
  >>> a, b = {1, 5, 6, 8}, {5, 6}
  >>> a >= a, a >= b, b >= a
  (True, True, False)
  ```
- The `str` and `bytes` support `in` to indicate that subsequences are covered.

  ```py
  >>> a, b = "+31 6 12345678", "6 12345678"
  >>> a in b, b in a
  (False, True)
  ```
- The `range` and `ipaddress` Networks support `in` to indicate that specific items are covered.

  ```py
  >>> IPv4Address('192.0.2.6') in IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/28')
  True
  ```

Notably, while these operators may be transitive they are not symmetric. For example, `a >= b and c >= b` does not imply `b >= c` and thus not `a >= c` or vice versa.

Practically, one could model "number without country code" as the superset of "number with country code" for the same number. This means that `06 12345678 >= +31 6 12345678` and `06 12345678 >= +49 6 12345678` but not vice versa. In order to do a symmetric comparison, one would use `a >= b or b >= a` instead of `a == b`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While doable, I realise it's a bigger can of worms than I realized, so I'll stay away from my idea of overriding `__eq__`, and just use a seperate method.

Answer (score 2):

`__eq__` method should be transitive; at least it is what dictionaries assume.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        for element in self.values:
            if element is other:
                return True
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

x, y, z = A('x'), A('y'), A('z')
x.values = [x,y]
y.values = [x,y,z]
z.values = [y,z]

print(x == y)
--> True

print (y == z)
--> True

print(x == z)
--> False

print({**{x:1},**{y:2, z: 3}})
--> {x: 3}

print({**{x:1},**{z:3, y:2}})
--> {x: 1, z: 2}
```

`{**{x:1},**{y: 2, z:3}}` is the union of two dictionaries. No one expects a dictionary to delete a key after updating it.

```
print(z in {**{x:1},**{y:2, z: 3}})
--> False
```

By changing the order in the union you can even get different sized dictionaries:

```
print(len({**{x:1},**{y:2, z: 3}}))
--> 1

print(len({**{x:1},**{z:3, y:2}}))
--> 2
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is transitivity of ``==`` but rather (un)symmetry of ``{**a, **b}``/``{a: ..., b: ...}``. Given ``a, b = {"k": 1}, {"k": 2}`` it is well accepted that ``{**a, **b}`` is different from ``{**b, **a}``. A better comparison might be ``{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}`` versus ``{**{x:1},**{y:2, z: 3}}``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well yes, those things can be different, but the keys must be exactly the same. The values may be changed by changing the order since they are written over; however, every key inserted to the dictionary should be present there unless they are deleted. My point is not that the created dictionaries are different but that their keys are different.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Looks like I underestimated the size of the can of worms, so I'll just leave `__eq__` alone, and use a seperate method.

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##dY/BSsQwEIbveYoBL8mSLk2LIMEKe/EJvJeoWVoo3TrJStPSZ69JoyXoOpfJzPf/k5nB2ebSlw8Drutbp4yBkyTg412foa7bvrV1TY3uzhw@VXfVLOIQoXvcmlBFSBKr/tiNF9toTIyo7RV7UK@GJjOyqIsVg0cQ6bhGmeZ74N9JeapEPeC/SmMx@ZMRMnJwHCZ/wYmKnPEtHe/jQ3jBgG1v6QhVBY6RO8iyJ3jBcOtGgLqAphsomnbyrDqzo/lwmEcpFu6zk4XfQEK5LD/aWeShvqWeZOlXlsUvseAghIRiWdcv) would be simpler and more natural.